# How to get host private network address in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I've tried something like this:

```
gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - set_fact:
        man_ip: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
      when: "item.startswith('10.')"
    - debug: var=man_ip
```

It works, but I have problem with servers where I use docker, 'cause docker containers also have interface adress started with `10.x.x.x`.

So, how can I get host private network address?

Comment: I guess that's quite tricky because the host itself does not know about the concepts of private/public IPs. It only knows it has IPs. So there probably is no clean solution. You either need to store that info somewhere or somehow detect it - maybe delegate a task to another host which would not have access to the private IP and try to ping it from there.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `ansible_all_ip_addresses` fact and the `ipaddr` filter.

```
{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ipaddr('private') | first }}
```

Note: You can check what *ansible facts* you have available with `ansible -m setup localhost`

**Edit:** You can also filter by ip using `ipaddr`

```
{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ipaddr('10.0.0.0/8') | first }}
```

Comment: I got a `No filter named 'ipaddr'` error. Had to install the netcommon collection `ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.netcommon` and also `netaddr`. If you installed ansible in the global python env you can just run `apt install python3-netaddr` on Ubuntu. I needed `pipx inject ansible-core netaddr` because I installed ansible via pipx.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
- debug: var="ansible_eth0['ipv4']['address']"
```

or

```
- debug: var=ansible_eth0.ipv4.address
```

Comment: Does `ansible_eth0['ipv4']['address']` always contains private network address?

Comment: No, it depends on how it was set up or in worst case: random (had some problems with it ;-) )

Comment: Of course, if you have eth1 enabled or on wireless, you have to choose the correct interface. For me, it always worked. I verified it on vanilla install/setup.

Comment: @helloV I use servers at SoftLayer. So, it doesn't guarantee that private network will be always in eth0.

Answer (score 1):

### Old solution

`ipaddr` is deprecated now:

```yaml
- debug: var="{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ipaddr('private') | first }}"
```

will lead to:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Use 'ansible.utils.ipaddr' module instead. This feature
will be removed from ansible.netcommon in a release after 2024-01-01.
```

### New Solution

You need to install:

```bash
sudo pip install netaddr    # system wide
pip install --user netaddr  # or for current user
```

Then next snippet will work:

```yaml
- debug: var="{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ansible.utils.ipaddr('private') | first }}"
```

See [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/docsite/filters_ipaddr.html) for more filtering examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].private_ipv4
```